# Complete your Data safety form - red alert in Publishing overview of Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Does somebody know, how the **red alert** in Publishing Overview of Google Play Console - **Complete your Data safety form** - should be perceived?

Like simple common warning for the developers or specific alert about any mistake of the developer?

[image: Red alert in Publishing overview]

Point is that I filled out the form Data Safety on the start of publishing my first version of the app. The app is approved and published on the Google Play. And the Data Safety information provided is visible on Google Play for the users.

Now I'm waiting for review of the second app update and since yesterday I observe this banner. Although the form is filled from the very beginning of the approved project. You can find the screenshot below.

[image: Data safety form is filled]

**Is this a common notification and can be ingnored if Data Safety form is filled or something wrong in my case?**

Comment: We have the same issue on our side...

Comment: At the same time today I've got approving of my app update and changes in metadata, but this red banner is still on display... I don't understand if I should worry about this or not, if my Data Safety Section is filled from the first app publication on Google Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert disappeared by itself. I did nothing for this.